# How can I get this buffered writer to write one line at a time? JAVA

Tags: java, bufferedwriter

I am creating a little program that will amend driver letters saved in a program file. The method works in the sense that it locates the file correctly and amends the drive letter correctly.

However when I open the file after it has been changed all the Directory listings are all on one line but they need to be 1 directory per line. I've tried saving each individual line to an Array List then printing them out like that but that didn't seem to work for me so was wondering if anyone could help?

Much appreciated.

P.S. Been messing around trying to make it work and also now ran into another issue where it is now printing them all out into one line but with spaces in between e.g:

S:\ D A T A\ S A G E\

```
public class copy
{

private String newDriveLetter;
private String line;
private Path[]sageFolders;
private FileReader fileReader;
private BufferedReader bufferedReader;
private FileWriter fileWriter;
private BufferedWriter bufferedWriter;
private List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();



    public void scanFiles() throws IOException{

       try
       {
        System.out.println("Sage 2015 is Installed on this machine");
        File companyFile = new File(sageFolders[8] + "\\COMPANY");
        fileReader = new FileReader(companyFile);
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader); 

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
           if(line.contains("F"))
           {
               line = line.replace("F:\\","S:\\");
               lines.add(line);

           }

        }
        //Close the Readers
        fileReader.close();
        bufferedReader.close();

        fileWriter = new FileWriter(companyFile);
        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

        for(String s : lines)
        {
            bufferedWriter.write(s);
        }

        bufferedWriter.flush();
        bufferedWriter.close();

       }
       catch(FileNotFoundException e)
       {
          System.out.println("File not Found: Moving onto next Version"); 
       }

}
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but you should consider using the constant File.separator instead of hard coding backslashes in your filename strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [`readLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--) reads a whole line, and then tosses away the line ending. From the documentation:

> A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached

So you have to add it back again, possibly using the preferred line ending for your platform:

```
bufferedWriter.write(String.format("%s%n", s);
```

here `%s` is the `String` and `%n` is the platform dependent line ending.

Alternatively, as Ransom Briggs indicates, you may use `newline()`. `newLine()` is easier to read and will perform slightly better:

```
bufferedWriter.write(s);
bufferedWriter.newLine();
```

I've left the `String.format` method in as it is a more general approach of adding newlines to strings.

Answer (score 1):

Try PrintWriter - so `new PrintWriter(bufferedWriter).println(s)`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this after bufferedWriter.write(s);:

```
bufferedWriter.write(System.getProperty("line.separator", "\n"));
```

This will add the system specific line separator, or "\n" if the system property is not set.

Comment: BufferedWriter provides a newLine() method which does the same thing.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine()

Comment: @RansomBriggs Yes, `newLine()`. I was just about to add that.

Comment: You still can add it :)